# Failing with the Webjobs validation script

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs

I am running the below script to validate my Webjobs whether they properly stopped or not after running my Webjobs stop and start scripts though PowerShell task in VSTS.But the below script is sometimes working properly and some times not properly.Because even after stopping my Webjobs,the validation script is saying the webjobs are not stopped.I am not sure why the script is throwing the error.I have double checked with the azure portal Whether the jobs are really stopped/started But in azure ,webjobs are stopped and started successfully but my validation script is throwing the error.Please help me on this.

Validation Script:

```
$ResourceGroupName="XXX"
        $AppService="XXXX"
        $Apiversion="2016-08-01"
        $errorsJobs=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $continuejobs=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
        foreach($webJob in $continuejobs){
Write-Host $webJob
        $status=$webJob.Properties.status
        if($status -ne "Running"){
          $errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name)
        }}
      if($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0){
    $result=$errorsJobs -join ";"
    Write-Error $result
    }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: After stopping my webjobs,The above validation script will run and its failing and showing the webjobs list which are not stopped/started.But when I check in Azure ,my webjobs are stopped properly.But my validation script saying not stopped.So I think the above script has some flaw.That I need to be fixed.I am not sure what was the flaw. If you can see my above script,It will check whether my webjobs are properly started or not.

Comment: Can someone please help me here?

Comment: How do you stop webjobs? Add `Write-Host $status` to output current status. (`$status=$webJob.Properties.status Write-Host $status`)

Comment: Hi MSFT, Can you please explain what are these above 2 lines which you commented even I am already added in the above script right.Please let me know what else you needed ? I have shared my script @ https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhxcdc5Gsy7Yc1VVF  for the webjobs stop.Please find the script and help me out With your script.

Comment: @MSFT,please help me here.

Comment: Can some one please help here?

Comment: Hi Pals,Any body help me here kindly?

Comment: Hi Friends,Can anybody please help me on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Continuous Webjobs Stop and Start properly done or not through PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788684/how-to-check-continuous-webjobs-stop-and-start-properly-done-or-not-through-powe)

Comment: My issue got resolved @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788684/how-to-check-continuous-webjobs-stop-and-start-properly-done-or-not-through-powe ..