# How to check Continuous Webjobs Stop and Start properly done or not through PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

Can anyone please suggest me how to accomplish the validation of webjobs stop and start properly happened or not ? Currently,I am stopping and starting the webjobs through PowerShell but I need to validate after the stop and start whether properly done or not.Please share your thoughts on this.As I am continuously searching online and blogs for the proper solution no once can provide the exact solution to this.I am running the PowerShell scripts through VSTS using VSTS PowerShell Task.Or else please update any other way to validate webjobs from VSTS ?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Hi Clijsters, I have the script with me but I am not sure where is the flaw.So I have posted that script in the stack forum but didn't get any response from anyone.So I have opened the new thread on the same issue.I keep on asking people to help me on my issue.Since I didn't get response I have opened this new thread.If you can help me on this,I will share my existing thread opened @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694580/failing-with-the-webjobs-validation-script?noredirect=1#comment82376212_47694580   .Please help here and let me know where is the error.

Comment: Much appreciated if you can help me on my issue.

Comment: ".. validate after the stop and start whether properly done or not .."  I assumed you meant it did stopped and started respectively.   Simple use the same powershell (instead of POST start/stop), do GET on the job itself - it will give u info about current status and history.

Comment: You need to @[fullname] in your comment, otherwise others can't receive the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tasks a few seconds to stop the webjob, so you can check the status after few seconds. For example:

```
[object]$paramObj=Get-Content "d:\a\r1\a\continuous\Scripts\Webjobs_Parameters.json" |ConvertFrom-Json 
    $userName =$paramObj.userName 
    $password =$paramObj.password
    $webAppName =$paramObj.webAppName
    $resourceGroup=$paramObj.resourceGroup
    [object[]]$webJobs=$paramObj.webJobs
$Apiversion="2016-08-01"
$webJobArr=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($wj in $webjobs)
    {
    $webJobArr.Add($wj.name)
     if($wj.typeName -eq "continuous")
     {
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName "$webAppName/$($wj.name)" -Action stop -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
      Write-Host "continuous"
     Write-Host "$wj.name is Stopping"
     }
    }
$tryCount=4
 $i = 1
 while($i -lt $tryCount){
 $errorsJobs=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
 Start-Sleep -s 5
 Write-Host "starting $i try......."
 $i +=1

  $continuejobs=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceName $webAppName -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
foreach($webJob in $continuejobs)
{
if($webJobArr -contains $webJob.Properties.name){
    if($webJob.Properties.status -ne "Stopped"){
        $errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name)
    }
}
}
if($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0){
$result=$errorsJobs -join ";"
Write-Host "Some jobs are not stopped: $result. Try to check again"
}
else{
Write-Host "All jobs are stopped."
break
}
if(($i -eq $tryCount) -and ($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0)){
Write-Error "Some jobs are not stopped: $result."
}

 }
```

Update 1:

```
param(
[string]$currentEnv
)

[object]$paramObj=Get-Content "d:\a\r1\a\DSPPortalJobs\WebJobs_scripts\WebJob_list.json" |ConvertFrom-Json
   $userName =$paramObj.$currentEnv.userName
    $password =$paramObj.$currentEnv.password
    $webAppName =$paramObj.$currentEnv.webAppName
    $resourceGroup=$paramObj.$currentEnv.resourceGroup
    [object[]]$webJobs=$paramObj.$currentEnv.webJobs
$Apiversion="2016-08-01"
$webJobArr=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
     foreach($wj in $webjobs)
        {
        $webJobArr.Add($wj.name)
}
$tryCount=4
 $i = 1
 while($i -lt $tryCount){
 $errorsJobs=New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
 Start-Sleep -s 5
 Write-Host "starting $i try......."
 $i +=1

  $continuejobs=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceName $webAppName -ResourceType Microsoft.web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion 
foreach($webJob in $continuejobs)
{
if($webJobArr -contains $webJob.Properties.name){
    if($webJob.Properties.status -ne "Running"){
        $errorsJobs.Add($webJob.Properties.name)
    }
}
}
if($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0){
$result=$errorsJobs -join ";"
Write-Host "Some jobs are not Running: $result. Try to check again"
}
else{
Write-Host "All jobs are Running."
break
}
if(($i -eq $tryCount) -and ($errorsJobs.Count -gt 0)){
Write-Error "Some jobs are not Running: $result."
}

 }
```

Comment: I am running the above script but when any one of my webjob is running it shouldn't proceed with the next step..But the above script is saying that all jobs are stopped.I am running the above script in two   different scripts,one is to stop webjobs and another to validate the webjobs.So the validation is not working fine.Please help me here.I have attached my error log @  https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvMxvVJdKJlVhxr5ZCmTk6WNvZwp .Please check and help me out.

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT ,as per the above links which I shared,among my 4 webjobs,2 webjobs are running and 2 webjobs are not running.So as per the script it should fail but its not failing.So please help me.

Comment: You don't need to validate the webjobs in another task, just do it together. If you still want to validate it in another task, you can check the update of my answer. Which status you want to validate, running or stopped?

Comment: I have tried both ways. I ran the above script Together and separately both ways it's not validating properly. Can you try to test from your end by stopping some web jobs and running 2 webjobs and then you can run the above script. You will come to know what exactly the issue

Comment: I am running the above script in the both ways, one way with combining the script and other way is separately running the validation script but validation script is not validating properly when some jobs are running and some jobs are stopped state. So please test from your end and help me here kindly.

Comment: It works fine for me, the first script is used to stop webjobs and validate whether the status is stopped, the updated script is used to validate whether the status is running. So I would like to know the detail scenario, such as all webjobs detail, what you want for these webjobs, what's the detail code and json files.

Comment: It looks like the above script is working.I will run this script for another 2 days and will come back to you if any issues comes.Thanks  a lot for your support.Without your help,I can't do all these.Much appreciating your great help..

Comment: One small help,instead of checking for 3 tries in the validation script,my script should wait for 60 seconds after stopped/started the web jobs and then display which jobs are not running or not stopped.That's all I need in the log.where can I modify the script.

Comment: Just replace `Start-Sleep -s 5` to `Start-Sleep -s 60`.

Comment: @PRAVEEN What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @ starian chen-MSFT,I am really sorry for the delay in responding to this as I met with an accident these many days.Kindly understand .Now my issue is resolved chen..really thanks a lot for your help.I am accepting this answer.